# Get number of days, weekends and months from a list of dates

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of dates and I want to check how often occurs weekends, weeks, and months in the list of dates.

I have a list of dates from 1 year like `2023-01-01` to `2024-01-01`.

```json
[
  "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-01T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-02T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-03T23:00:00.000Z",
  ....
]
```

How can I convert it to an object like this:

```json
{
  "day": 12,
  "weekend": 5,
  "month": 5
}
```

Comment: So, you want a list of counts of *distinct* days, weekends, and months?

Comment: @Brad yes, I am new at javascript and doesnt know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add all your data inside [an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and then using the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, iterate over each date string.

There are 3 main variables.

1. `dayCount` to count the total number of days.
2. `weekendCount` to count the number of weekends.
3. `monthCount` to count the number of months.

Count the total number of days by increasing the `dayCount`.

If the date falls on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday), we increase `weekendCount` to keep track of the total number of weekends.

If the date is the first day of the month, increase `monthCount` to keep track of the number of months.

You're welcome, here's your final code.

```js
const dateList = [
  "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-01T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-02T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-03T23:00:00.000Z",
  // modify your array
];

let dayCount = 0;
let weekendCount = 0;
let monthCount = 0;

dateList.forEach((dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  dayCount++;

  // check if the current date is a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
  if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) {
    weekendCount++;
  }

  // check if the current date is the first day of the month
  if (date.getDate() === 1) {
    monthCount++;
  }
});

console.log("Days:", dayCount);
console.log("Weekends:", weekendCount);
console.log("Months:", monthCount);
```

You can make your code a little bit shorter by using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, and the `dayCount` is simply set to the length of the `dateList` array (guessing that each date is a new day).

```js
const dateList = [
  "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-01T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-02T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-03T23:00:00.000Z",
  // modify your array
];

// count the total number of days
let dayCount = dateList.length;

// count the number of weekends
let weekendCount = dateList.filter(dateStr => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  return date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6; // Sunday is 0, and Saturday is 6
}).length;

// count the number of months
let monthCount = dateList.filter(dateStr => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  return date.getDate() === 1; // check if it's the first day of the month
}).length;

console.log("Days:", dayCount);
console.log("Weekends:", weekendCount);
console.log("Months:", monthCount);
```

You can make your code even shorter by using [an arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and directly assigning variables.

```js
const dateList = [
  "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-01T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-02T23:00:00.000Z",
  "2023-02-03T23:00:00.000Z",
  // modify your array
];

let dayCount = dateList.length;
let weekendCount = dateList.filter(dateStr => new Date(dateStr).getDay() % 6 === 0).length;
let monthCount = dateList.filter(dateStr => new Date(dateStr).getDate() === 1).length;

console.log("Days:", dayCount);
console.log("Weekends:", weekendCount);
console.log("Months:", monthCount);
```

Comment: No way @Lightning Mcqueen Side Hussle is answering questions on stack overflow.

Comment: Yup, even cars answer questions on Stack Overflow, @LiamMorton. We flag too :-)

Answer (score 0):

use momentjs to manipulate date in javascript

Date of Month :

```
moment().date(Number);
moment().date(); // Number
moment().dates(Number);
moment().dates(); // Number
```

Day of Week :

```
moment().day(Number|String);
moment().day(); // Number
moment().days(Number|String);
moment().days(); // Number
```